# MYSQL Join tables and display data from a contact list

Tags: php, mysql

Table **users**:

```
  id firstname lastname    email         avatar
  1     Coman      Paul   x@y.com    ./images/a.png
```

Table **friendships**:

```
 id user1 user2
  1    1     2
  2    1     5
  3    3     1
  4    2     3
```

User `1` is friend with `2,3,5`

User `2` is friend with `1,3`

I tried this:

```
       $querym = mysql_query("SELECT  user1
       FROM    friendships
       WHERE   user2 = '1'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT  user2
      FROM    friendships
       WHERE   user1 = '1'"); 

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($querym);

if($numrows!=0)
{

Echo '<div id="members">    <ul >';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($querym))
{


$firstname = $row['firstname'];
$lastname = $row['lastname'];
$email = $row['email'];
$avatar = $row['avatar'];
Echo '
<li>
.............
```

It will display all my friend but i can;t see they're names...
I also tried

```
$querym = mysql_query("SELECT users.*, friendships.* FROM users, friendships WHERE     users.id=friendships.user1 AND( friendships.user1='1' OR friendships.user2='1')");
```

but I got an error...

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\OnTheRunningLine\membri.php on line 346

Please help me with a core for displaying my `friends(users.id=1)` and data about them with explaining why because i need to learn it.

Oh, and if you can show me a code that will display after these results, the other users that are not friends with `users.id = 1` would be great !

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be

```
select u.firstname, u.lastname,u.email,u.avatar from users u
inner join friendships f on f.user2 = u.id 
where f.user1 = 1
union
select u.firstname, u.lastname,u.email,u.avatar from users u
inner join friendships f on f.user1 = u.id 
where f.user2 = 1
```

I think given your intent.

Comment: not friends would be just changing the where statements, not sure how useful that query would be though...

Comment: i were still getting the same error until i added `$numrows = mysql_num_rows($querym) or die (mysql_error()); `  and i found out that: _Unknown column 'u.firstname' in 'field list'_.  I changed letter "u" in your code with "users" and it works like a charm ! **Thank you !**

Comment: Do you have any idea if it's possible to display the rest of users wich are not friends with that user (eg: id=1 ) ? I tried to replace "=" operathor with "!=" but it displays all users....

Comment: Something like Select u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.avatar from users u join (Select distinct user1 as auser from friendships where user1 <> 1 and user2 <> 1 union select disctinct user2 from friendhsips where user2 <> 1 and user1 <> 1) notmyfriends on notmyfriends.auser = u.id would be one way

Comment: It doesn't work...i want to display the result wich are not displayed in the first time(when i show the list of friends). It seems Your querry doesn't work because in the friendships table there are links between users that are friends of user.id=1, or not...so it will display all users...

Comment: Ask another question then mate.